# Getting NullPointerException in when array's size is not instantly assigned

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to learn Java and I am currently writing a program that will split an array of integers into two sub-arrays, one containing the positive values and the other the negative values.

Due to the fact that the sizes of the two sub-arrays can not be specified from the start (because this program should work on any array of integers) I wrote two methods which will calculate the sizes of the two sub-arrays (maxNeg and maxPos). Afterwards, the two sub-arrays (arrayNegative and arrayPositive) are initialized having the the two corresponding sizes.

The problem is that, when I try to populate the two arrays using the arraySorter(), the compiler gives me the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 error right at the first iteration inside the arraySorter() method.

Note 1: The issue doesn't occur when values are assigned to the maxNeg and maxPos variables from the start.

Note 2: I know this type of problem is usually solved using ArrayLists for storing the positives and negatives, but my assignment's requirements force me to do this using only arrays.

```
public class sortMethod {
public int max; // max = main array length
public int maxNeg; // the length of the final array that will store the
                    // negative integers
public int maxPos; // the length of the final array that will store the
                    // positive integers

public int[] intArray = new int[max];

public int getMaxNeg() {
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        if (intArray[i] < 0) {
            maxNeg++;
        }
    }
    return maxNeg;
}

public int getMaxPos() {
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        if (intArray[i] >= 0) {
            maxPos++;
        }
    }
    return maxPos;
}
public int[] negativeArray = new int[maxNeg];
public int[] positiveArray = new int[maxPos];
public int negIndex = 0;
public int posIndex = 0;

public void arraySorter() {
    for (int a = 0; a < max; a++) {
        if (intArray[a] < 0) {
            negativeArray[negIndex] = intArray[a];
            negIndex++;
            // System.out.println(negativeArray[0]);
        } else {
            positiveArray[posIndex] = intArray[a];
            posIndex++;
        }
    }
}

public sortMethod(int[] y, int z) {
    this.intArray = y;
    this.max = z;

}
```

Can someone explain why I'm keep getting the NullPointerException when using formulas to calculate the sizes of the two sub-arrays and why I don't get the error when values are assigned to 2 variables upon declaring them.

This is the main method where I created the test object:

```
public class ArraySort {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = { -12, 23, -22, 0, 43, -545, -4, -55, -43, -12, 0, -999};

    int z = array.length;
    sortMethod arrayTest = new sortMethod(array, z);

    arrayTest.getMaxNeg();
    arrayTest.getMaxPos();
    arrayTest.arraySorter();
```

}

Thanks and please excuse me if my question's formating is not compliant with the site's standards, it's my first and I will try to improve in the future.

Comment: `public int max;` Do you ever set this to something other than 0? When you do `public int max; public int[] intArray = new int[max];` max is 0 at that point.

Comment: Yes, i'm editing the question right for more details.

Comment: Problem still exists.

Comment: @eckes Can you please explain why the problem still exists? I thought that the problem noticed by @Takendarkk is covered by my constructor and the `int z = array.length;` statement.

Comment: The creation of the 3 arrays `intArray`, `negativeArray` and `positiveArray` happens in the initialiser. At this point the size variables `max`, `maxNeg` and `maxPos` are 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this code is executed

```
public int[] negativeArray = new int[maxNeg];
public int[] positiveArray = new int[maxPos];
```

`maxNeg` and `maxPos` is equal to 0, so it is normal to have an out of bound exception.

To get it to works, you could initialize the arrays directly in the method so your code would become :

```
public int[] negativeArray;
public int[] positiveArray;
public int negIndex = 0;
public int posIndex = 0;


public void arraySorter() {
    negativeArray = new int[maxNeg];
    positiveArray = new int[maxPos];
    for (int a = 0; a < max; a++) {
        if (intArray[a] < 0) {
            negativeArray[negIndex] = intArray[a];
            negIndex++;
        } else {
            positiveArray[posIndex] = intArray[a];
            posIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

Another part of your code that is wrong is the constructor of sortMethod. You give the array length to the maximum bound, but the maximum bound is actually length - 1. so change `this.max = z;` to `this.max = z - 1;`

Also, your algorithm does not sort numbers, it simply separate negatives of positives... If you want to sort an array of number you can simplify it in one line :

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

The order in which you define variables and methods in Java is not important. Your instance variables (e.g. your negativeArray and positiveArray) are created as soon as the class instance is created (and before the constructor is called). You therefore initialize both arrays with a size of 0.